# I get an error when Octave runs my Logarithm

Tags: octave, logarithm

i am trying to get my function to work.
The values for "time" and "value" are taken from a raw data txt file (time and value are raw data parsed by my programm).
Just for the purpose of demonstration i chose diffrent values for time and value.
I can also get other calculations to work, i just have a problem with getting my Log fn to work.

```
%Declaration (a time between 0-60s, a value between  0-200) 
  ti= (0.5);
  q = (3);
  L1 = 3/(log10(2));%9.9658 
  L2 = log10(2/3); %-0.17609
  time = 40 %anything between 0 and 60
  value = 90 %anything between 0 and 200

%f2 = Log Function 
  f2=figure(2);
  y2= 9.9658*log10(1/(time*value*0.5*10*-0.17609));
  x2=time;
  fplot(x2,y2); 
  xlabel('Time in s'), ylabel('Value in db'),title('Calculations'),set(gca,'fontsize',15); grid on
```

The result i get is:

```
error: Question: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 38x1, op2 is 38x1)
error: called from
    Question at line 11 column 5
```

if anyone had this error before i would be thankfull for help.
Best regards

Comment: That code does not generate that error though. You must have had an array as input somewhere, or maybe a symbolic variable? `fplot` takes a function handle as input, but you give it a value of 40 in this example. When you create a [mre], make sure it reproduces the issue in a clean Octave session.

Comment: Jeah it actually works when i change "fplot" to "plot". Tahnks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to this question is as Cris Luengo pointed out in his answer to boot up a clean Octave session and change "fplot" to "plot".

```
  plot(x2,y2); %works now
```

Big Thanks!